# Vlookup across two worksheets return yes or no

Tags: excel, ms-office, spreadsheet

I'm trying to compare values across two sheets, Sheet1 column F and Sheet2 column F.  I would like to return a 'Yes' if the values match and a 'No' if they don't in Sheet 2 column G.

The have the following formula but it isn't working. Can someone take a look at it and tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong?

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet2!F2,Sheet2!1:1048576,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!F:F,Sheet1!1:1,0))),"Yes","No")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter below formula in `Cell G2` of `Sheet2` and drag/copy down as required.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(F2,Sheet1!F:F,0)),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are making the formula way too complicated. Why not just do this?

```
= IF(F2=Sheet1!F2,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: I want to return a yes if the value in F2 Sheet 2 exists in clomn F Sheet 1, otherwise it should return No.